# Remove a node from a sorted List by passing the value as an argument

Tags: java

Hello I am trying to remove a node from an ordered List by passing the value as an argument but i always get and Null pointer exception. Below is the method i am using to do this.

```
public void sortedDelete(int social){
    if(sortedIsEmpty()){
        System.out.println("List is Empty");
    }
    else if(sortedSize() == 1){
        if(head.getData() == social)
            head = null;
    }else{
        SocialNode x = head;
        if(x.getData() == social)
            head = head.getNext();
        else{
            int count = 1;
            x = x.getNext();
            while(x!= null){
                if(x.getData() == social && x.getNext() != null){
                    sortedGet(count-1).setNext(sortedGet(count+1));
                }else if(x.getData() == social && x.getNext() == null){
                    sortedGet(count-1).setNext(null);
                }
                x = x.getNext();
                count ++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Full class code is here 
[Implementation of a List in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804680/implementation-of-a-list-in-java/14804705#comment20735662_14804705)

Comment: What line do you get the exception at?

Comment: The last `else` should be an `else if(x.getData() == social)` I guess. But this shouldn't lead to a NullPointerException if I see it right.

Comment: Andre i managed to get the method to work and i edited the code. But the problem now is that if i have duplicated how can i remove all of them with one loop. As it is now it just removes the first one that is found.

Comment: I don't read your algorithm entirely, but to compare two objects you MUST use equals. Overwrite this method in your SocialNode class and then update your code.

Comment: @davidbuzatto he is just comparing integers

Comment: @André: You are right. I thought hes was comparing the nodes... I think its time to sleep :D

Answer (score 0):

Better way to use arrayList but i can see using of arrayList is not allowed in your case. In that case you need to drop old array and create a new array of size 1 less than original array and copy old array to new array. you can take help of below code.

```
package com.rais;

public class ArrayExample {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

        numbers = remove(numbers, 4);

        for (int i : numbers) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

    }

    public static int[] remove(int[] originalArray, int elemntToDelete)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++)
        {
            if (originalArray[i] == elemntToDelete)
            {
                int[] newArray = new int[originalArray.length-1];
                System.arraycopy(originalArray, 0, newArray, 0, i);
                System.arraycopy(originalArray, i+1, newArray, i, originalArray.length-i-1);
                return newArray;
            }
        }
        return originalArray;
    }

}
```

Comment: Alert! You should use equals to compare objects!

Comment: That was a premetive int array.

Comment: I need to use a LinkedList for this. I have to create it from scratch. I managed to delete the element but i can not do i recursively.

Comment: @Real: Sorry, i thought you are dealing with its list nodes... Time to sleep :D

Comment: @Leon you said that you are not allowed to use arrayList or other to complete your task. and now you are saying you can use LinkedList. I request you please ask right question.